# Facebook login button with JS SDK - How to get the user's email?

Tags: javascript, email, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I want to use facebook's SDK to make a button that allows those who have facebook to log into my site through facebook. But for that I need their username, email, and profile picture(if possible). I want to send them to php with _POST, as if they were submitted by a form. I'm new to this so i barely understand what the code facebook gave me is doing.

I get the user's name, which means that it connects to FB fine, but it doesn't give me their email.

The emails for the facebook accounts that I tested are public and verified, so that shouldn't be the problem. I think I should have scope="email" somewhere, but not sure where to put it?

so far:

```
response.name = good;
response.email = undefined;
response.picture = undefined;
```

Most of the code is from facebook's [guide for setting up the button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web)

Except `get_fb_info()` is a function I made to send the response variables to the server side.

The facebook login button code:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="small" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true"></div>
```

javascript that i need to initialize the JavaScript SDK, check login status, get the fb user's username, image, and email, and send them to a php file:

```
    <script>
// This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);

    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        // Logged into your app and Facebook.
        testAPI();
    } else {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' + 'into this app.';
    }
}

function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '(my app id)',
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.8'
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });

};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/debug.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

// Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
        console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
            'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
    get_fb_info();//puts the users info into variables and calls the ajax file to log into fixit
}

// getting basic user info
function get_fb_info() {
    FB.api('/me', 'GET', {fields: 'name,id,email,picture'}, function(response) {
        console.log("FB NAME: "+response.name);
        console.log("FB ID: "+response.id);
        console.log("FB EMAIL: "+response.email);
        console.log("FB PICTURE: "+response.picture);

        if(response.email == "undefined"){
            LoginForm.gotoSignUp(0);
        }

        data_string = 'fb_id=' + response.id + '&name=' + response.name + '&email=' + response.email + '&picture=' + response.picture;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_fb_login.php",
            data: data_string,
            success: function (data) {console.log(data);}
        })
    }, {scope: 'email'});
}
</script>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I think you try to remove this line: js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/debug.js";